# Sql Syntax giving unknown syntax error

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am having a problem with my mysql statement.

basically the code works perfectly when inserting, but as soon as the `addnew` variable=false and it switches to update it gives me an error that i cannot solve.

The Code:

```pascal
procedure Tadddomain.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
PrevSql:String;
ID:String;
begin
With Datalive.domains Do
 Begin
  id:=fieldbyname('id').AsString;
  Active:=False;
  prevsql:=sql.Text;
  Sql.Clear;
  Params.Clear;
  Addparam(Datalive.domains,'client_id',ftinteger,datalive.clients.FieldByName('id').AsString);
  Addparam(Datalive.domains,'domain_name',ftString,Edit1.Text);
  Addparam(Datalive.domains,'register_date',ftdate,DateTimePicker1.Date);
  Addparam(Datalive.domains,'registered_until',ftdate,DateTimePicker2.Date);
  if addnew=true then
    Sql.Text:='Insert into domains (client_id,domain_name,register_date,registered_until) VALUES (:client_id,:domain_name,:register_date,:registered_until)'
  Else if addnew=False then
    Sql.Text:='Update domains (domain_name=:domain_name, register_date=:register_date, registered_until=:registered_until) where id='''+id+'''';
  Showmessage(sql.text);
  execsql;
  sleep(100);
  sql.Text:=prevsql;
  active:=True;
  done:=True;
  adddomain.Close;
 End;
end;
```

The Error:

> Project project1.exe raised exception class EZSQLException with message 'SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '(domain_name='asd',register_date='2014-11-09',registered_until='2015-11-09') w' at line 1'.

Any Assistance would be great, I have searched and searched and cannot find the fault.

---

**Update:**

I changed the edit code as suggested below, and now no errors apear what so ever. But also nothing happens. It does not edit the record.

```pascal
if addnew=true then
    Sql.Text:='Insert into domains (client_id,domain_name,register_date,registered_until) VALUES (:client_id,:domain_name,:register_date,:registered_until)'
  Else if addnew=False then
   Begin
    sql.Add('Update domains');
    sql.Add('set domain_name=:domain_name,');
    sql.Add('register_date=:register_date,');
    sql.Add('registered_until=:registered_until');
    sql.Add('where id=:id');
   End;
```

Comment: update command in mysql goes as `update table set col1 = :col1,col2=:col2 where id = :id` using prepared statement.

Comment: I'm not sure about adding parameter values before the query is parsed (or compiled by the underlying DBMS). But there are other issues in your code. Parameter of type `ftInteger` you are filling with a string value. `AddNew` as some global scope variable cannot be anything else than `False` if testing it for `True` fails. Pointless `Sleep`, using `with`...

Comment: Hi @Tlama I did not notice the integer and string fault. But it has not caused a problem with the inserting.
The addNew variable is a boolean that just tells the code whether or not to insert, if it is false, then it tries to update.

But you have not addressed the problem. You mentioned everything but the main problem.

Comment: You are inserting a `client_id` from `Datalive.Clients.FieldByName('id')` but updating a record with ID taken from `Datalive.Domains.FieldByName('id')`. Is that correct ? About the problems I mentioned; you think they are not important, but cleaning your code is one way to spot the problem by yourself. Debugging is first way of course.

Comment: @Tlama yes that is correct, the table I am trying to edit has a `id` field and a `client_id` field. This `client_id` links the two records so that when you select a specific client you can filter out the right fields under the domains table.

Comment: What is the reason for this **golden ring** programming *one query component rules all*? You will save a little bit memory but you will loose a lot of performance. Use one component for each task (read, insert and update) and just pass the param values. `if addnew then LQuery := DomainInsertQuery else LQuery := LUpdateQuery; LQuery.ParamByName('domain_name').Value := ...; LQuery.ExecSQL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.
If i define the parameters before i use the `sql.add()` function the parameters are discarded.
When I moved the

```
Addparam(Datalive.domains,'client_id',ftinteger,datalive.clients.FieldByName('id').AsString);
  Addparam(Datalive.domains,'domain_name',ftString,Edit1.Text);
  Addparam(Datalive.domains,'register_date',ftdate,DateTimePicker1.Date);
  Addparam(Datalive.domains,'registered_until',ftdate,DateTimePicker2.Date);
```

to just before the `execsql;` the problem was solved.

Comment: That's the problem with the moving target questions, the title does not fit the with the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Update syntax is like this

```
Update domains 
set domain_name = :domain_name, 
    register_date = :register_date, 
    registered_until = :registered_until
where id = :id
```

Comment: @Marcel . . . You cannot get *exactly* the same error, because your error messages says the problem is near "(domain_name . . ." and that is not in Juergen's query.

Comment: @Gordonlinoff thank you for pointing out the line difference. I did not click that.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the "client_id" parameter not the "id" parameter you use in the update statement.

```
where id = :id
```

should be

```
where id = :client_id
```